# DC motor noise filtering

Tags: filter, dc-motor, bypass-capacitor

I have some brushed motors near to a 433 MHz RF receiver. They're controlled by a 490 Hz PWM signal. The electrical noise they produce is not a problem for the circuit, but it is for the receiver.

How can I reduce the noise, at least on the frequencies interfering with the transmitter?

I read that putting a ceramic capacitor across the motor's terminals and one from each terminal to the motor's case would help; if it's true, what size should they be? I unfortunately don't have technical information about the motors. I'm quite sure they're the same as [those](https://hobbyking.com/en_us/mini-quad-brushed-motor-8-5x20mm-4-pack.html), but there isn't much data on that site...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I read that putting a ceramic capacitor across the motor's terminals and one from each terminal to the motor's case would help; if it's true, what size should they be?

You read the truth. Keep the leads to the caps short. 10nF is a reasonable sort of size, but you can go bigger or smaller if you have other sizes to hand.

Comment: Caps to motor case may help *if the motor case is well grounded*. Otherwise, the whole motor becomes a noise radiator.

Comment: @glen_geek does "grounding a motor's case" means connect it directly to ground?

Comment: @noearchimede no, it means connecting it to PSU ground that's powering it, or the case that's enclosing the equipment, ideally they are one and the same thing.